# How to get the names of git branches which were merged into a merge

Tags: git

We develop feature branches which we merge to master and delete.  Then we merge master to a branch named "release".

Having checked out the release branch head, I need to see the names of all the branches that were merged to master and deleted.

I try the following but it only gives me the names of the branches that still exist.

```
git branch --list -a --merged
```

Comment: You can't. They're gone. Git does not maintain any information about what branches names were used to create a merge commit. If this information is important to you, consider embedding it explicitly in your merge commit messages.

Comment: Git's branch names have no actual meaning anyway. I'd argue that instead of a *branch name*, the merge commit should have a human-written message describing the *goal* of the merge. Sometimes the default message is close enough to that, especially if the human making up the branch name puts a lot of thought into the branch name at the time they make it up.

Answer (score 0):

The default commit message in a merge includes the names of both the merged branch and the target branch. Have you checked there?

Something like *Merge branch 'feature1' into develop*.

Comment: Note that Git will leave off the `into` part in some cases. Specifically, Git has a weak notion of the name of the "main branch". In older versions of Git this is hardcoded as the literal string `master`; in the latest Git there is a `git config` knob to change this. If the current branch, at the time someone runs `git merge`, is the "main branch", Git will omit the `into <name>` part.